# How to force React (functional component using hooks) to create a new component from scratch on props change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**TLDR**

Is there a way to force React to recreate a component (**functional component using hooks**) from scratch instead of re-rendering it on a `prop` change?

**EDIT**

The key attribute DOES work. The problem I was having was due to the state update sequence that I was doing. The first update was trying immediately to render a component that needed the last update to be already done.

---

I'm working on a component called `<AddProductWidget>`, that will get the following `props` about a product and need to display its details. It belongs to a page with a search bar that you fill the productID and it gets the product details from a cloud function.

It's rendered like this:

```
  <AddProductWidget
    userImages={props.productDetails.userImages}    // Array of strings (urls)
    title={props.productDetails.title}
    stars={props.productDetails.stars}
  />
```

**AddProductWidget.js**

It renders a `<UserImages>` component that lets the user clicks on some images to select before saving to the database. So it needed a `state` to 'remember' which images have been clicked by the user.

```
function AddProductWidget(props) {

  const [userImagesSelected, setUserImagesSelected] = useState(
    () => {
      if (props.userImages && props.userImages > 0) {
        return new Array(props.userImages.length).fill(false);
      }
      return null;
    }
  );

  // IT renders the <UserImages> component
  // The code here is simplified

  return(
      <UserImages
        userImages={props.userImages}
        userImagesSelected={userImagesSelected}
        setUserImagesSelected={setUserImagesSelected}
      />
  );

}
```

The initial state of that array `userImagesSelected` should be the same length of the `userImages` array and be filled with `false` values, that will become `true` once the user start clicking on the images. If the product doesn't have user images, `props.userImages` will be `null` and `userImagesSelected` should also be `null`.

Everything is working as expected when I load the first product. Whether it has images or not, everything is being displayed correctly.

**The problem:**

The problem is when I load a product with zero images, and subsequentely I load another product with 5 images, for example. Basically the `props` for `AddProductWidget` will change (since it received a new product), but because React seems to be trying to use the same component instance, I get an error, because my `UserImages` component will try to render the selected images information, but the state of `userImagesSelected` will still be `null`, because the last products had no images.

When I was working with classes, I could force React to recreate a component instance using the `key` attribute, but that doesn't seem to work with hooks, since the following code didn't solve my problem:

```
  <AddProductWidget
    key={productID}
    userImages={props.productDetails.userImages}    // Array of strings (urls)
    title={props.productDetails.title}
    stars={props.productDetails.stars}
  />
```

**Question**

Is there a way to force React to recreate a component (**functional component using hooks**) from scratch instead of re-rendering it on a `prop` change?

**Extra**

A found a way around it, but it seems a bit hacky, even though it's on React docs. It basically uses a state to detect when `props` change and calls `setState()` during render. I would like it better to recreate my component from scratch.

[Hooks FAQ: How do I implement getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: what makes you think the key is not working? a new key would make the component un-mount and mount again

Comment: I tried that bit of code and it didn't work. Should it work with a functional component using hooks? I'll give it another try and will let you know.

Comment: Just retried and confirmed that it doesn't work.

Comment: A small and concise run-able example would help

Comment: Working on it! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how you decided that a different `key` won't re-mount the component but it should do that (are you sure the key has changed?)

Here is a running example showing this

```js
function Test() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Test was mounted');
    return () => {
      console.log('Test was un-mounted');
    };
  }, []);

  return "hi there, I'm Test";
}

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState("Change me...");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)} />
      <br />
      <Test key={val} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: You are correct! The key should be working. I've also managed to get it working on the example that I was building. I got some bug on my code. Do you know if when it re-mounts the parent, does it automatically remount its children as well?

Comment: Yup the entire tree